# Path with HTML and thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a little Java, Spring, thymeleaf webapplication with bootstrap.

**My Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/productmerger")
public class SetupController {

    @Autowired
    private TradingModel tradingModel;


    @RequestMapping(value = "start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    //@ResponseBody //can be deleted due to thymeleaf
    public String start(ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.put("productList", tradingModel.getAvailableProducts());
        return "start";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String startPost(@RequestParam("Products") String[] products, HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
        tradingModel.getContentList().clear();
        for (String product : products) {
            tradingModel.getContentList().add(new Product(product));
        }
        return "redirect:/handleDetails";
    }

}
```

**My HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="template :: head">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="start.html">
        <h2>Chose what you want to trade</h2>
        <label>
            <select th:name="Products" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="productList" type="java.util.List"*/-->
                <option th:each="product : ${productList}"><a th:text="${product}"></a></option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button th:type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div th:replace="template :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**the source code from my Browser**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap-select/1.12.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="start.html">
        <h2>Chose what you want to trade</h2>
        <label>
            <select class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" name="Products">

                <option><a>Table</a></option>

                <option><a>Glas</a></option>

                <option><a>Fork</a></option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
<footer>
    <script src="webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/bootstrap-select/1.12.0/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**part of my template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="title" type="String"*/-->
    <title th:text="${title}">Hello</title>
    <link th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap-select/1.12.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

**Path of start.html**

D:\Programme\Dropbox\HelloSpring3\src\main\resources\templates\start.html

Path of the css

C:\Users\N-rG.m2\repository\org\webjars\bootstrap\3.3.7-1\bootstrap-3.3.7-1.jar!\META-INF\resources\webjars\bootstrap\3.3.7-1\css\bootstrap.min.css

**My Problem:**

Behind that link in the Browser which is correctly displayed:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

is actually wrong because as soon as I hover on it or click it, it redirects me to

http://localhost:8080/productmerger/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css

So the /productmerger/ part here is just wrong. How can I get rid of it?

Please help me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you update the post with the configuration of you head template?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I just did so.

Comment: Have you check your `addResourceHandlers` ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I have no method like that. But I'll check google and see if it helps me. If you have any further suggestions, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a *context-relative* URL by adding a `/` first:

```xml
<link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

See [Thymeleaf Standard URL Syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) for details.